# How to call two nth-child in a table?

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, html-table

I have a table 4*5 (4 columns, 5 rows).

I want to add a class to the cells on the first column and after the 2nd row.

My code :

```
$("tr>td:nth-child(1) tr:nth-child(n+3)").addClass("ClassName");
```

This is not working. Any idea on how to do this?

PS. [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/japeljoff/CnUw6/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To select cells that are **both** at the first column and after the 2nd row, use the CSS selector:

```
tr:nth-child(n+3) td:nth-child(1)
```

jQuery:

```
$("tr:nth-child(n+3) td:nth-child(1)").addClass("ClassName");
```

Your fiddle, updated: http://jsfiddle.net/CnUw6/1/

Comment: Perefecto! this is what i wanted to do. Now, do you know why do you have to specify first the row (tr) then the column (td) ?

Comment: Yes. Because you first have to select the parent, then the children. For instance, the selector `$('aa bb')` means every `bb` that is a child of `aa`. If you select something like `$('td:something tr:something-else')`, in your example, there will be no results, as there are no `tr` that are children of a `td`.

Comment: On the other hand, when you use: `$("tr:nth-child(n+3) td:nth-child(1)")` you say: first get me the rows (`tr`s) from the third on. Now, get me their children that belong to the first column (`td`).

Comment: That makes a lot of sense @acdcjunior ! I don't know if is appropiate to ask a second question on this thread ... but now i have a second question: Same instance as before, add class to first column and after 2nd row, but now i want to add a class to the last row. Why is not overwriting the values on the last row? please see :  http://jsfiddle.net/japeljoff/CnUw6/2/

Comment: You are adding the class `highlight` to the `td`, and the class `highlight2` to the `tr`. As a `td` is "more specific" than a `tr`, its style will prevail. Change the selector to `tr:nth-child(n+5) td` and it will select (and add the classes) to the `td`s instead of the `tr`. This way, due to the order of the classes, `highlight2` will be the one in effect: http://jsfiddle.net/CnUw6/5/ (notice the order of the classes' declaration matter: http://jsfiddle.net/CnUw6/4/ )

Comment: Thanks so much! this solve all my problems. Seems stupid, but it was driving me bananas! Thanks again!

Comment: Not at all. This is stuff is tricky and, I say for myself, it took a bit of brain racking to get me there. Glad I could help!!! Would you mind accepting the answer, then? http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/219205

Answer (score 1):

You need a comma between your elements:

```
$("tr > td:nth-child(1), tr:nth-child(n+3)").addClass("ClassName");
```

Comment: This method will select All elements in column 1 and all elements after the 2nd row. I just want to Select all cells just in the column 1 but after the 2nd row, make sense?